# Get YouTube video url or YouTube video ID from a string using RegEx

Tags: python, regex

So I've been stuck on this for about an hour or so now and I just cannot get it to work. So far I have been trying to extract the whole link from the string, but now I feel like it might be easier to just get the video ID.

The RegEx would need to take the ID/URL from the following link styles, no matter where they are in a string:

```
http://youtube.com/watch?v=iwGFalTRHDA
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwGFalTRHDA&feature=related
https://youtube.com/iwGFalTRHDA
http://youtu.be/n17B_uFF4cA
youtube.com/iwGFalTRHDA
youtube.com/n17B_uFF4cA
http://www.youtube.com/embed/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=r5nB9u4jjy4
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-ZRX8984sc
http://youtu.be/t-ZRX8984sc
```

So far, I have this RegEx:

```
((http(s)?\:\/\/)?(www\.)?(youtube|youtu)((\.com|\.be)\/)(watch\?v=)?([0-z]{11}|[0-z]{4}(\-|\_)[0-z]{4}|.(\-|\_)[0-z]{9}))
```

This catches the link, however it also breaks down the link in to multiple parts and also adds that to the list too, so if a string contains a single youtube link, the output when I print the list is something like this:

```
('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Idn7ODPMhFY', 'https://', 's', 'www.', 'youtube', '.com/', '.com', 'watch?v=', 'Idn7ODPMhFY', '', '')
```

I need the list to only contain the link itself, or just the video id (which would be more preferable). I have really tried doing this myself for quite a while now but I just cannot figure it out. I was wondering if someone could sort out the regex for me and tell me where I am going wrong so that I don't run in to this issue again in the future?

Comment: I strongly recommend splitting the URL into its components first using the [`urlparse` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) first, and then only operate on the URL `path` component using regular expressions. This will significantly simplify matching hostnames against a list of domains, dealing with `https` vs. `http` etc.

Comment: This is like an email verification problem.  I would look into *lookarounds* for regex and try and build it this way.  http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html

Answer (score 7):

Instead of writing a complicated regex that probably work not in all cases, you better use tools to analyze the url, like `urllib`:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs

url = 'http://youtube.com/watch?v=iwGFalTRHDA'

def get_id(url):
    u_pars = urlparse(url)
    quer_v = parse_qs(u_pars.query).get('v')
    if quer_v:
        return quer_v[0]
    pth = u_pars.path.split('/')
    if pth:
        return pth[-1]
```

This function will return `None` if both attempts fail.

I tested it with the sample urls:

```
>>> get_id('http://youtube.com/watch?v=iwGFalTRHDA')
'iwGFalTRHDA'
>>> get_id('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwGFalTRHDA&feature=related')
'iwGFalTRHDA'
>>> get_id('https://youtube.com/iwGFalTRHDA')
'iwGFalTRHDA'
>>> get_id('http://youtu.be/n17B_uFF4cA')
'n17B_uFF4cA'
>>> get_id('youtube.com/iwGFalTRHDA')
'iwGFalTRHDA'
>>> get_id('youtube.com/n17B_uFF4cA')
'n17B_uFF4cA'
>>> get_id('http://www.youtube.com/embed/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=r5nB9u4jjy4')
'r5nB9u4jjy4'
>>> get_id('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-ZRX8984sc')
't-ZRX8984sc'
>>> get_id('http://youtu.be/t-ZRX8984sc')
't-ZRX8984sc'
```

Comment: The `.query` can have multiple components (e.g. `v=` and `feature=`) so to just grab the `v=` which is the id, you could use `re.search(r'v=([\d\w]+)', parse.query).group(1)`

Comment: @CoryKramer: what if there is a `foov=bar` in the query?

Comment: Hmm good point. Maybe a lookbehind for either `?` or `&` before the `v`

Comment: Hey, this seems to only work if the string it is looking at is just the url, like you gave in your example. I need to take the url or video id from an entire string, such as -  `'This is my link right here. I wonder if this actually works? http://youtube.com/watch?v=iwGFalTRHDA'`. When I run your code with that string in the `url` variable, I get the following output - `This is my link right here. I wonder if this actually works`

Comment: @JohnYuki: fixed. A small typo.

Comment: Yeah I spotted that before I made my comment, however the code still isn't outputting anything for me. This is the code, exactly the same as yours, but when I run it, nothing appears in the shell window and the program just stops - http://i.imgur.com/GA7zL3H.png

Comment: @JohnYuki: but if you want to let it write something in non-interactive mode. You need to add a `print` statement.

Comment: Okay thanks I see that now. However, back to the problem I stated in my original comment to you. I need to actually get the video url or video ID from a string first. I am taking comments from Reddit that contain YouTube video urls. I then need to extract the video url from the string that gets returned when it finds a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the approach I'd use, no regex needed at all.

*(This is pretty much equivalent to `@Willem Van Onsem`'s solution, plus an easy to run / update unit test).*

```
from urlparse import parse_qs
from urlparse import urlparse
import re
import unittest


TEST_URLS = [
    ('iwGFalTRHDA', 'http://youtube.com/watch?v=iwGFalTRHDA'),
    ('iwGFalTRHDA', 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwGFalTRHDA&feature=related'),
    ('iwGFalTRHDA', 'https://youtube.com/iwGFalTRHDA'),
    ('n17B_uFF4cA', 'http://youtu.be/n17B_uFF4cA'),
    ('iwGFalTRHDA', 'youtube.com/iwGFalTRHDA'),
    ('n17B_uFF4cA', 'youtube.com/n17B_uFF4cA'),
    ('r5nB9u4jjy4', 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=r5nB9u4jjy4'),
    ('t-ZRX8984sc', 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-ZRX8984sc'),
    ('t-ZRX8984sc', 'http://youtu.be/t-ZRX8984sc'),
    (None, 'http://www.stackoverflow.com')
]

YOUTUBE_DOMAINS = [
    'youtu.be',
    'youtube.com',
]


def extract_id(url_string):
    # Make sure all URLs start with a valid scheme
    if not url_string.lower().startswith('http'):
        url_string = 'http://%s' % url_string

    url = urlparse(url_string)

    # Check host against whitelist of domains
    if url.hostname.replace('www.', '') not in YOUTUBE_DOMAINS:
        return None

    # Video ID is usually to be found in 'v' query string
    qs = parse_qs(url.query)
    if 'v' in qs:
        return qs['v'][0]

    # Otherwise fall back to path component
    return url.path.lstrip('/')


class TestExtractID(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_extract_id(self):
        for expected_id, url in TEST_URLS:
            result = extract_id(url)
            self.assertEqual(
                expected_id, result, 'Failed to extract ID from '
                'URL %r (got %r, expected %r)' % (url, result, expected_id))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 2):

I really advise on @LukasGraf's comment, however if you really must use regex you can check the following:

```
(?:(?:https?\:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube|youtu)(?:(?:\.com|\.be)\/)(?:embed\/)?(?:watch\?)?(?:feature=player_embedded)?&?(?:v=)?([0-z]{11}|[0-z]{4}(\-|\_)[0-z]{4}|.(\-|\_)[0-z]{9}))
```

Here is a working example in regex101:
https://regex101.com/r/5eRqn2/1

And here the python example:

```
In [38]: r = re.compile('(?:(?:https?\:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube|youtu)(?:(?:\.com|\.be)\/)(?:embed\/)?(?:watch\?)?(?:feature=player_embedded)?&?(?:v=)?([0-z]{11}|[0-z]{4}(?:\-|\_)[0-z]{4}|.(?:\-|\_)[0-z]{9}))')
In [39]: r.match('http://youtube.com/watch?v=iwGFalTRHDA').groups()
Out[39]: ('iwGFalTRHDA',)
In [40]: r.match('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwGFalTRHDA&feature=related').groups()
Out[40]: ('iwGFalTRHDA',)
In [41]: r.match('https://youtube.com/iwGFalTRHDA').groups()
Out[41]: ('iwGFalTRHDA',)
```

> In order to **not catch** specific group in regex you should this: `(?:...)`

Comment: @CoryKramer, As mentioned in the first sentence of my answer, I really advise **not** doing it with regex, however if you have to (or if, lets say, you want to practice your regex skills), this is one way to solve this.

Comment: I know I saw that, I just couldn't miss the opportunity to use that particular meme

Comment: hehe :) ok. Care to vote the answer, now that I gave you the opportunity to use it? :D

Comment: I tested your regex with this URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2vjPBrBU-TM , and it doesn't seem to work. I replaced `[0-z]{11}` with `[0-z-]{11}` , and it worked.

Comment: @Dekel I tried this but I keep getting `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'` as the output. This is the code - http://i.imgur.com/tFoOyeR.png

Comment: Did you try to use the regex101 link in my answer as a start?

Comment: @Dekel I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: Did you check the regex101 link in my answer? Do you understand how to work with it?

Comment: @Dekel Not really no. I do understand some basic things about it, but I tried for an hour to get RegEx to work on my own but couldn't figure out how to. And now the code you have given me is just returning "None", rather than the video url or id, and I'm not sure why seeing as you managed to get it working?